# Is it possable to see were a t.co link was originaly posted / refered from?

Tags: google-analytics, twitter, referrer

We get quite allot of referal traffic from t.co/ links showing up in Google Analytics, which is great, but with any decent source of traffic its really helpful to be able to see where it was originally refereed to so you can try and recreate / capitalise on it.

I guess its a shorted twitter link but past that i have no idea were i came from / who posted it, i took the link and pasted it into both Google and Twitter search but those both came back with no results, any ideas.. i know with bt.ly you can have link Analytics which is great from a marketing perspective, is there anything similar with t.co ?

Answer (score 2):

You can view the referral traffic by login into to twitter and the same way you would search for hashtags copy and paste the URL, it'll display all the users who interacted with that URL. This process is very time consuming and not that rewarding since it only gives you the satisfaction of saying ok, Jimmy shared my link and then Sarah too...

To look at the bigger picture you should be looking into using [Twitters own Analytics](https://analytics.twitter.com/)